# Why doesn't the annotation processing tool (apt) not operate after installing Java 9?

Tags: java, macos

I installed Java 9's JDK, and cannot find apt.  I've exported my JAVA_HOME as below:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

But when I attempt to use it, I get this error:

```
 Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)
```

How can I fix it?  I don't know why it can't find the apt binary, and I want to use it.

Comment: To potential close voters:  This is referring to the annotation processing tool.

Answer (score 3):

[apt is *long* gone.](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/an-apt-ending-draws-nigh)

> After being deprecated in JDK 7, the `apt`command line tool and the entirely of its associated API is on track to be removed from JDK 8 within the next few months.

Its scope of removal has been covered in [JEP 117](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/117), which was delivered back in Java **8**.

If you want to use anything to do with annotation processing, your best bet is to use the `javax.annotation.processing` libraries.